# A normal operator with no real roots

Tags: linear-algebra

Can anyone give an example of a normal operator on a positive-dimensional real vector space whose characteristic polynomial has no real roots?

Answer (score 0):

For example, take any invertible skew-symmetric real operator:
$$
A=\pmatrix{0&-1\\1&0}
$$
will do.

Comment: Any insights on how you come up with it?

Comment: You want a matrix with no real eigenvalues. So, you should think of rotations.